# How to align images in responsive design

Tags: responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to align images in responsive design. First image should be aligned to the left, lat to the right and middle ones- centered with even spacing between them.

Doing this in fixed width layout would be easy, but it's not in responsive. WOuld nice to get any ideas on this one.

Thanks!

http://www.bootply.com/132522

Answer (score 0):

```
ul {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li{
  /*float: left;*/ <- Remove!
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
}

li:first-child {
    float: left; 
}

li:last-child {
    float: right; 
}
```